# Taylor theorem and Newtons Method. [Rudin : Problem 5.25]

Tags: real-analysis

### The Problem

> Suppose $f$ is twice differentiaable on [a,b], $f(a)<0$, $f(b)>0$, $f'(x)\geq \delta >0$, and $0\leq f''(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Let $\xi $ be the unique point in $(a,b)$ at which $f(\xi)=0$.
>
> Choose $x_1\in (\xi, b)$, and define $\{x_n\}$ by
>
> $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$
>
> Use Taylor's theorem to show that
>
> $x_{n+1}-\xi=\frac{f''(t_n)}{2f'(x_n)}(x_n-\xi)^2$
>
> for some $t_n\in (\xi, x_n)$

### My Attempt

Okay my attempt at this:

$x_{n+1}-\xi=x_n-\xi-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$

Since $f(x_n)=f(\xi)+f'(\xi)(x_n-\xi)+\frac{f''(t_n)}{2}(x_n-\xi)^2=f'(\xi)(x_n-\xi)+\frac{f''(t_n)}{2}(x_n-\xi)^2$ for $t_n\in (\xi, x_n)$ we have

$x_{n+1}-\xi=x_n-\xi-\frac{f'(\xi)(x_n-\xi)+\frac{f''(t_n)}{2}(x_n-\xi)^2}{f'(x_n)}=\frac{(x_n-\xi)}{f'(x_n)}(f'(x_n)-f'(\xi)-\frac{1}{2}f''(t_n)(x_n-\xi))$

### My problem

Now here I am sort of stuck. Since I could use taylors theorem again for $f'(x_n)$ and replace it with $f'(\xi)+f''(s_n)(x_n-\xi)$ for some $s_n\in (\xi,x_n)$. But if I do that I end up with

$\frac{(x_n-\xi)}{f'(x_n)}(f''(s_n)(x_n-\xi)-\frac{1}{2}f''(t_n)(x_n-\xi))$

which would prove the statement if $s_n=t_n$. But working out examples with $f(x)=x \ln{x}$ on the interval $[.5,3]$ I find that equality not to be true.

### Worked Example

Let $f(x)=x\ln{x}$ be defined on $[.5,3]$ let $x_1=2$ we show that $s_1\neq t_1$.

$2\ln{2}=f(2)=f(1)+\frac{f'(1)}{1!}(2-1)+\frac{f''(t_1)}{2!}(2-1)^2=(1)+\frac{1}{2t_1}$ so $t_1=\frac{1}{4\ln{2}-2}$

$f'(2)=f'(1)+f''(s_1)(2-1)$

$1+\ln{2}=1+\frac{1}{s_1}$ so $s_1=\frac{1}{\ln{2}}\neq \frac{1}{4\ln{2}-2}=t_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea: We try to develop $f$ at $x_n$ instead of $\xi$.

$$
0 = f(\xi) = f(x_n) + f'(x_n) (\xi-x_n) + (1/2) f''(t_n)(\xi-x_n)^2
$$
with $t_n$ between $x_n$ and $\xi$.

Then
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} - \xi &= x_n - \xi - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \\
&= \frac{f'(x_n) (x_n - \xi) - f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \\
&= \frac{f''(t_n)(x_n - \xi)^2}{2f'(x_n)}
\end{align}

Note: Using $x_n$ as point for development is what one does for the Newton-Raphson iteration too.

Comment: If this is true then why does my worked example(see the original question)  show that your second relation isn't true?

Comment: @user160110 I think I got it now.