# Exercise 5.25 in Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, induction

Suppose $f$ is twice differentiable on $[a, b], f(a)<0, f(b)>0, f'(x)\ge\delta>0$, and $0\leq f''(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in[a, b]$. Let $\xi$ be the unique point in $(a, b)$ at which $f(\xi)=0$.

Part (b): Choose $x_1\in(\xi, b)$, and define $\{x_n\}$ by $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})}$. Prove that $x_{n+1}<x_n$ and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\xi$.

My attempt: We use Induction. It is easy to show that $x_2<x_1$. Now suppose $x_{k+1}<x_k$, then easily $f(x_{k})>0$ and $x_{k+2}=x_{k+1}-\frac{f(x_{k+1})}{f'(x_{k+1})}$. But where do I go from here? How do I show that $f(x_{k+1})>0$? I tried to prove that $x_{k+1}\in(\xi, b)$, but induction does not seem to work there as I failed to show that $x_n\in(\xi, b) \forall n\in\Bbb{N}$. Please help.

Comment: Perhaps you could quote the question in its entirety so that users who don’t have that particular text on-hand would know what you’re talking about.

Comment: Firstly, you should post the entire question (parts (a) and (b) ) for those who don't have a copy of Baby Rudin. To help with your question, you can't assume that $x_{k+1}<x_k,$ as that is assuming the result... To prove that $x_{k+1} < x_k$ for all $k$, I would try to show that $\varepsilon<x_{k+1}<x_k$ for all $k,$ rather than try to show that $f(x_{k+1})>0.$ To do this, you'll need to use the fact that $f$ is convex. If $f$ were concave then $x_{k+1}<\varepsilon.$

Comment: There have been multiple editions of this book over the years.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it doesn't state the exercise.

Comment: @J.Murray: Great advice - I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Brian Borchers: I see - thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @Shaun: I apologize for violating the protocols!

Comment: It's okay. I see that you have included it now. My downvote is now an upvote and I have removed my vote to close.

Comment: @Shaun: Thanks for the help! I am a fairly slow typist, but I tried my best to post the whole problem as soon as I read the comments.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: I appreciate the tips! That was indeed one of my attempts, but $\epsilon<x_{k+1}<x_k \forall k$ did not work for me either. I shall try again using $f$ is convex - that is something I failed to notice.

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530164/taylor-theorem-and-newtons-method-rudin-problem-5-25?rq=1

Comment: @AdamRubinson: I tried, to no avail. The solution in the related post does not claim that $f''(t_n)\neq 0$. Even in the solution by UW-Madison, the author fails to explain why $f'(c)<f'(x_n)$ (recall the problem states that $f''(x)=0$ is indeed possible, hence $f'(c)$ could very well be equal to $f'(x_n)$). Dr. Kit-Wing Yu does not include sufficient detail in his errata either. Honestly, I can not even show that $x_2\neq \xi$.